Differences between ReturnType this indexed method and dot notation
Coming from here How to infer a class method unknown return type and use it in a property
Trying to infer what initialize method returns and apply this type to prop.
This code works:
class Base {
  method_1() {}
}

class Child extends Base {
  method_2() {}
}

abstract class AbstractClass {
  prop: ReturnType<this['initialize']>

  abstract initialize(): Base
}

class UserClass2 extends AbstractClass {
  initialize() {
    return new Child()
  }

  someMethod() {
    this.prop.method_1()  // Valid, no TS error
    this.prop.method_2()  // Valid, no TS error
  }
}

And this is returning always the Base type:
class Base {
  method_1() {}
}

class Child extends Base {
  method_2() {}
}

abstract class AbstractClass {
  prop: ReturnType<typeof this.initialize>

  abstract initialize(): Base
}

class UserClass2 extends AbstractClass {
  initialize() {
    return new Child()
  }

  someMethod() {
    this.prop.method_1()  // Valid, no TS error
    this.prop.method_2()  // Error!
  }
}

What's the difference between using in the ReturnType the indexed way ReturnType<this['initialize']> and typeof of the dot notation ReturnType<typeof this.initialize>?

There's no difference with ReturnType really. The difference is that this is implemented as a generic type, and when you index into a generic type with a non-generic index, TS widens the generic to its constraint, as mentioned in this ms/TS#33181 comment.  So, if T is generic, the type T["xxx"] is going to stay generic, while the type typeof t.xxx is not. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz Yep, that was a good explanation. Thanks.

The this type is implicitly generic:
The polymorphic this type is implemented in microsoft/TypeScript#4910 "by providing every class and interface with an implied [generic] type parameter that is constrained to the containing type itself".  In some sense your classes are equivalent to these:
abstract class AbstractClass<T extends AbstractClass<T>> {
  prop!: ReturnType<T['initialize']>;
  abstract initialize(): Base
}

class UserClass2<T extends UserClass2<T>> extends AbstractClass<T> {
  initialize() {
    return new Child()
  }
  someMethod(this: T) {
    this.prop.method_1()  
    this.prop.method_2()  
  }
}


Indexing a generic with a specific key widens to the constraint
The type this['initialize'] is an indexed access type which means "the type of the initialize property of the this type". That indexed access type is also implicitly generic. In a subclass of AbstractClass, it will refer to the initialize property of that subclass.
You might expect that if you have a value of type this (such as the value named this) and you index into it with the key 'initialize', you'd get that indexed access type, and therefore that typeof this.initialize would be the same as this['initialize']. But that's not what happens:
abstract class AbstractClass {

  abstract initialize(): Base
  
  goodInit!: this['initialize'];
  // (property) AbstractClass.goodInit: this["initialize"]

  badInit!: typeof this.initialize
  // (property) AbstractClass.badInit: () => Base

}

You can see that badInit is of type () => Base, which is completely independent of this, while goodInit is of the type this["initialize"] as expected.
The reason this happens is that when you have a generic value and you index into it with a non-generic key, the compiler will automatically widen the generic value to its constraint.  So inside AbstractClass, the type of this.initialize will just be () => Base. And so typeof this.initialize is not polymorphic and subclasses won't see anything different.  See this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#33181.
The reason why that happens is essentially for performance and ease of use. If every mention of this kept things generic, then the compiler would have to synthesize lots of generic types all over the place, hurting performance. Additionally, it would make it harder to use generic values, since they'd never "cash out" to specific types. So if this were to be changed, the compiler would get slower and there's be a lot of code breakage.

Put those together and you get your answer; it has little to do with ReturnType. It's that this["initialize"] and typeof this.initialize are two different types; the former is generic, while the latter is not.
Playground link to code
